# ffmpeg - How to append the stream duration of an HLS chunk as a suffix ffmpeg?

Tags: unix, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Is there a way to get the stream duration of a HLS chunk, while transcoding, in order to append it as a suffix at the end of *.ts files ?
I know I can use ffprobe afterwards but performance would be better using ffmpeg one way and adding the suffix on the fly

Thank you !

Comment: You don't need `ffprobe`, the duration is already in the playlist's `EXTINF` tags.

Comment: I dont use the playlist that is generated I dynamically create a playlist with a PHP that outputs a m3u8. At the moment I ask ffprobe for the stream duration of every segment that I dynamically select, but its too consuming and very sloppy.

Comment: It's hard to tell without some example code.